# Answerer down-voting question if OP doesn't acknowledge his/her answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have noticed that sometimes, when an answer doesn't receive attention from the OP (and others), there is a fresh down-vote on the question (which wasn't there previously). I shrugged this off as coincidence the first 3 times. The fourth time I just couldn't help but wonder, what if it isn't coincidence?

Do any of you people ever down-vote the question if your answer doesn't receive attention as a form of revenge (can't think of a better word)?

Comment: Looks like coincidence to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, never, I just go give more answers.

Comment: Well, you answered the question to the point.. but no idea about what is the use of the question in the first place?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, well, there's a lot of discussion questions like that, where their only purpose is to generate discussion. (Not saying it's really useful)

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, From what I hear, this meta is very different from StackOverflow. When I found a discussion tag, I naturally assumed that questions like these were welcome on this site. As for the use, go figure :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it could be some form of revenge-downvoting, but most likely the answer bumped the question up to the front page, it got more attention and some of the new viewers thought the question wasn't very good.

(It would be nice to see some examples to confirm.)

Comment: I would have provided examples, but all these questions I speak of are long-buried. I did not bookmark them. It would take quite a lot of time (which I don't have) to find them!

Answer (score 0):

> Do any of you people ever down-vote the question if your answer doesn't receive attention as a form of revenge?

No. I do not downvote in this situation. Because when I earned the privilege to vote down, I read [that privilege rules](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down):

> #### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

So I don't downvote if the question is fine but the OP doesn't response me.